# Creating an SRPN calculator in Java

Tags: java, stack

In a work interview I was tasked with creating an SRPN (Saturated Reverse Polish Notation) calculator from scratch. They gave me insight into one that they had created themselves (without showing their coding) and asked for me to replicate it exactly.

The code would require the user to write in the terminal their numbers and operators in order to get an answer in a specific format.
E.g.

```
'3
3
*
='
```

would print 9.

they also used other operators such as +,-,*.^,% in order to calculate different answers.
The calculations even went further with equations such as:

```
'3
3
*
4
4
*
+
='
```

which in other words translates to '(3x3)+(4x4)'.

They also used the letter f, where when you would type this letter, it would bring the previous numbers back into the equation. Almost like a memory.

Well, safe to say that I'm more of a Python wizz than Java since I had no clue what to do. Just from small experience in Java, i understand that a stack was created initially, then they initialised all the operators (+,-,%,*,^) giving them the correct functions in order to create the answers. No idea how they did the f function. But i understand that they most likely used a buffered reader in order to gather the user inputs so the equation can be constructed; and in turn create an answer.

The problem is i have no idea how to do it and i'm keen to learn. All the answers online are pretty varied and broad/ ChatGPT is no help as well.

Are there any Java experts that may be willing to share how a code like this may look?

Thanks guys

Comment: `They also used the letter f, where when you would type this letter, it would bring the previous numbers back into the equation. Almost like a memory.` can you rephrase this, I really cannot understand what this function does

Comment: Apologies. Writing f brings back the previous answer. e.g. 3+3= 6. 5+f=11. f being 6. If i do f again now, it will be the previous answer; in this case it comes 11

Comment: "how a code like this may look?" A stack to accumulate the operands, a `Scanner` to read the input. In a loop read each token, if it is a number, put it onto the stack; if it is an operation, remove the operands from the stack and execute the corresponding operation, putting the result onto the stack (if not `=`) A variable to hold the last result, for `f`; and some checking for "Saturated"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to build a Polish tree from the input and a general rule based on the input is that the operator follows its operands. You have binary operators usually, such as + and * and you can safely rely on that.

f is storing something:

> They also used the letter f, where when you would type this letter, it would bring the previous numbers back into the equation. Almost like a memory.

If I understand this literally - and given the context I have no other option - then f basically instructs the system to paste all numbers above it. Hence you need to store the previous numbers in a queue-like structure (First In First Out), that is, not exactly a queue, because you do not want to remove the values, but nevertheless, you will want to operate with them in the order you received them.

I'm not sure what operators you need, but if you want the same operators as before, then you can store the operators in the queue as well. Think of this queue-like structure like a temporary input source whenever f triggers it.

Comment: much too complicated, advantage of RPN: a stack can be used to save the operands/results; no need to build the tree. And `f`, as far as I understand based on comment to the question (still insufficient), can be implemented by a single variable holding the last result, filled when `=` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

this is the minimal RPN calculator in java, it does not handle errors and edge cases, but it should give you idea how to start implementing such things:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        var stack = new Stack<Double>();
        var answerStack = new Stack<Double>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            var input = scanner.nextLine();
            switch (input) {
                case "+": stack.push(stack.pop() + stack.pop()); break;
                case "-": var s = stack.pop(); stack.push(stack.pop() - s); break;
                case "*": stack.push(stack.pop() * stack.pop()); break;
                case "^": var p = stack.pop(); stack.push(Math.pow(stack.pop(), p)); break;
                case "%": var d = stack.pop(); stack.push(stack.pop() / d); break;
                case "=": var r = stack.pop(); answerStack.push(r); System.out.println(r); break;
                case "f": stack.push(answerStack.pop()); break;
                default: stack.push(Double.valueOf(input)); break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: suggestion `while (true)` -> `while (scanner.hasNextLine())`